# Max elements with tail function in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming

I'm messing around with the assignments on Coursera's Functional Programming course and I've stumbled upon something weird. This problem requires you to find the max of a List of integers using only the methods `isEmpty`, `head`, and `tail`. My solution is a recursive function that catches an `UnsupportedOperationException` if there are no more elements. The solution doesn't seem to work however, and I think it is because the exception is never caught.

```
  /**
   * This method returns the largest element in a list of integers. If the
   * list `xs` is empty it throws a `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.
   *
   * You can use the same methods of the class `List` as mentioned above.
   *
   * ''Hint:'' Again, think of a recursive solution instead of using looping
   * constructs. You might need to define an auxiliary method.
   *
   * @param xs A list of natural numbers
   * @return The largest element in `xs`
   * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if `xs` is an empty list
   */
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = 
  {
    def maxOfTwo(value1: Int, value2: Int) = {
      if(value1 > value2) value1
      else value2
    }
    println(xs.size)
    try { maxOfTwo(xs.head, max(xs.tail)) }
    catch { case noTail: UnsupportedOperationException => xs.head }
  }
```

When I use the following code, which is just replacing the `UnsupportedOperationException` with `Exception` everything works perfectly. Am I missing something here?

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = 
  {
    def maxOfTwo(value1: Int, value2: Int) = {
      if(value1 > value2) value1
      else value2
    }
    println(xs.size)
    try { maxOfTwo(xs.head, max(xs.tail)) }
    catch { case noTail: Exception => xs.head }
  }
```

Comment: You should add the `homework` tag. :)

Comment: @AlexCruise Does it really count as homework if it's for an MOOC that isn't even in session any more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't catch java.util.NoSuchElementException with UnsupportedOperationException pattern.
And BTW your code is throwing exception twice. The second exception is thrown by catch block, by invoking `xs.head`.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I thought that List.tail threw an UnsupportedOperationException?

Comment: `List.tail` throws `UnsupportedOperationException` if the traversable collection is empty, but `List.head` throws `NoSuchElementException` and is invoked first.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be better:

```
  def max(xs: List[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    @tailrec
    def go(l: List[Int], x: Int): Int = {
      l match {
        case Nil    => x
        case h :: t => if (x > h) go(t, x) else go(t, h)
      }
    }
    if (xs.isEmpty) None else Some(go(xs.tail, xs.head))
  }
```

Result type is `Option`, because list can be empty.

**UPDATE**:

It fails when `UnsupportedOperationException` is used, because when you try to access `xs.head` of an empty list you should also catch `NoSuchElementException`. It works with `Exception`, because it's a base class of these two exceptions.

Comment: Yeah that works, but I'm more interested in why my solution works when I use Exception and fails when I use UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Because when you try to access xs.head of empty list you should also catch java.util.NoSuchElementException. Exception is base class of two that is why it works.

Answer (score 0):

How about just thinking functional?

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) 0 else xs.head + sum (xs.tail)  
}
```